# bring latest from repository

Tags: svn

for build purpose, we need to sync the code with the one present in $IMGDIR.
Just doing svn update is enough? Or is there any way to get the list of files that have been modified in trunk and check out individually? I need to write a script for the same. Earlier we were using harvest. we used to query the harvest database for state="System Test" and get the list, then checkout.

Vadiraj

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by 'to sync the code with the one present in $IMGDIR' ?

If you want to build the latest version of the code, assuming that your code is checked out from the same branch/trunk, then yes, `svn update` is sufficient.